# storage parameter

Tags: storage, deploy, parameter

Hello I don't think I filled my storage correctly, when compiling it returns me: token null...

```
(pair (pair (pair (pair (address %admin) (big_map %allowances (pair address address) nat))
                      (pair (big_map %ledger nat address) (big_map %metadata string bytes)))
                (pair (pair (nat %next_token_id) (big_map %operators (pair address (pair address nat)) unit))
                      (pair (mutez %price) (big_map %reverse_ledger address (list nat)))))
          (pair (pair (string %serial)
                      (big_map %token_metadata nat (pair (nat %token_id) (map %token_info string bytes))))
                (pair (big_map %tokens address nat) (nat %total_amount)))) ;

 
settings :'(Pair (Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" } { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e })) (Pair (Pair { } 1 { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" }) (Pair { 1 } ))) (Pair (Pair "SERIAL" { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) }) (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" 1 1)) '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below should have the correct format.

```
(Pair (Pair (Pair (Pair "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" {  }) (Pair { Elt 1 "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" } { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f36663138333737353065366562383163646434666633363230663738613133322f7261772f653238396663353037326235613931353134383936376239613433333765313835343731363561322f636f6e74726163745f6d6574612e6a736f6e })) (Pair (Pair 1 {  }) (Pair 1 { Elt "tz1i3veHnR4ogcwKmgugcqnunTmTYP8s8ZAr" { 1 } }))) (Pair (Pair "SERIAL" { Elt 1 (Pair 1 { Elt "" 0x68747470733a2f2f676973742e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6f7269616e6131332f35313763373231396531383639333938613765666631343335623862653237392f7261772f326337336132613564353365626466313662633864623831643837343236353964323763646462332f6e66745f6d6574612e6a736f6e }) }) (Pair {  } 1)))
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-leaf-l1es8j)